# How could I use Spinner to show list of String dates

Tags: java, android

I wand to use Spinner to show list of String dates from Room Database with using observer  but the dates not appeared in the spinner even though I didn't get an error of null reference message, I do not know what is the problem  And this is my code

````
public class DailyDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Spinner mSpinner;
    private List<NumberOfNotification> listDate;
    private NotificationSpinnerAdapter notificationSpinnerAdapter;
    private TextView mTextView;
    private LiveData<List<NumberOfNotification>> numberLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_data);

        mSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        listDate = new ArrayList<>();

        notificationSpinnerAdapter = new NotificationSpinnerAdapter(this, listDate);
        mSpinner.setAdapter(notificationSpinnerAdapter);
        mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(listDate.get(position).getNumberOfNotificationOfToday()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
        initList();
    }

    public void initList() {
        final NotificationViewModel notificationViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NotificationViewModel.class);
        notificationViewModel.getAllDatesOfNumberOfNotification().observe(this, new Observer<List<NumberOfNotification>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<NumberOfNotification> numberOfNotifications) {

                for (NumberOfNotification n : numberOfNotifications) {
                    System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + numberOfNotifications.size());
                    listDate.clear();
                   
                    listDate.addAll(numberOfNotifications);
                    notificationSpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
        });
        System.out.println("test date" + listDate);
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void initList() {
    final NotificationViewModel notificationViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NotificationViewModel.class);
    notificationViewModel.getAllDatesOfNumberOfNotification().observe(this, new Observer<List<NumberOfNotification>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<NumberOfNotification> numberOfNotifications) {
                listDate.clear();
            for (NumberOfNotification n : numberOfNotifications) {
                System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + numberOfNotifications.size());

               
                listDate.addAll(numberOfNotifications);


            }
        }
    });
                notificationSpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    System.out.println("test date" + listDate);
}

}
```

Comment: does this line prints any output?
                System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + numberOfNotifications.size());

Comment: it didn't print anything

Comment: It could mean numberOfNotifications list is empty ?

Comment: updateForNightMode [allowRecreation:false, currentNightMode:16, newNightMode:16, activityHandlingUiMode:false, baseContextAttached:true, created:false, canReturnDifferentContext:true, host:com.barmej.wecare.activities.DailyDataActivity@b956de9]

Comment: I don't think listDate.addAll(numberOfNotifications); is adding anything to the list.You need to debug this to confirm if data is added to list or not